# Hook to apply cache with _embed in Wordpress REST Api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to cache the Wordpress REST Api response with the `_embed` parameter using the `rest_pre_echo_response` hook. This works good and I can cache the outgoing response. But I can´t find a good hook to apply the cache. Using the `rest_pre_dispatch` hook I get the problem that the embedded links are still replaced since the cached response have embedded links. Is their a hook prior `dispatch` that skips the embedding of links? Or is their a better solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your filter 'rest_pre_dispatch' add

```
if ( $in_cache ) {
    $_GET['_embed'] = '0';
}
```

Comment: Like your idea. Guess the point is to not evaluate the embedded links? `response_to_data( $result, isset( $_GET['_embed'] ) )`. But i need to set `$_GET['_embed'] = null` to get the result of `isset( $_GET['_embed'] )` equal `false`